# MySQL SELECT / GROUP BY losing NULLs

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following two tables:

```
> select * from t1;
+-------+-------+
| text1 | text2 |
+-------+-------+
| a     | NULL  |
| b     | c     |
| d     | e     |
+-------+-------+

> select * from t2;
+-------+-------+-------+
| text1 | text2 | value |
+-------+-------+-------+
| a     | NULL  |     1 |
| a     | NULL  |     2 |
| a     | NULL  |     3 |
| b     | c     |     1 |
| b     | c     |     2 |
| d     | e     |     3 |
| f     | g     |     1 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

What I'm trying to do is join the two tables together, grabbing the minimum `value` for each `text1,text2` combination that is in `t1`.

Here's the query I have so far, with the result I'm getting:

```
> select text1, text2, min(value)
> from t1
> natural join t2
> group by text1, text2
> order by text1 asc;
+-------+-------+------------+
| text1 | text2 | min(value) |
+-------+-------+------------+
| b     | c     |          1 |
| d     | e     |          3 |
+-------+-------+------------+
```

So it's *almost* what I need, but as you can see, I'm losing the `a` values because the `text2` is `NULL`. Here is the result I'm expecting:

```
+-------+-------+------------+
| text1 | text2 | min(value) |
+-------+-------+------------+
| a     | NULL  |          1 |
| b     | c     |          1 |
| d     | e     |          3 |
+-------+-------+------------+
```

So what is wrong with my query that's filtering out those `NULL` values?

Note that `t2` may have other combinations of `text1` and `text2`, e.g. `('a','z')`, that I *don't* want in my result, hence why I have both `text1` and `text2` in my `GROUP BY` clause. At least, that's what I'm going for (clearly something's not working as I'd like it to).

Note, I'm using MariaDB version 10.3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to join with the `<=>` null safe operator.

```
SELECT t1.text1,
       t1.text2,
       min(t2.value)
       FROM t1
            INNER JOIN t2
                       ON t2.text1 <=> t1.text1
                          AND t2.text2 <=> t1.text2
       GROUP BY t1.text1,
                t1.text2
       ORDER BY t1.text1 ASC;
```

What you currently have translates to:

```
SELECT t1.text1,
       t1.text2,
       min(t2.value)
       FROM t1
            INNER JOIN t2
                       ON t2.text1 = t1.text1
                          AND t2.text2 = t1.text2
       GROUP BY t1.text1,
                t1.text2
       ORDER BY t1.text1 ASC;
```

And as `NULL = NULL` is not true the rows with the nulls don't match and therefore don't make it into the result.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a `NATURAL JOIN` or `USING()` here. Use the NULL-safe operator `<=>` in the ON clause instead, which will evaluate `NULL <=> NULL` to `1`, while `NULL = NULL` is `NULL`:

```
select t1.text1, t1.text2, min(value)
from t1
join t2
  on  t2.text1 = t1.text1
  and t2.text2 <=> t1.text2
group by t1.text1, t1.text2
order by t1.text1 asc;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ca2a1/1

Comment: Thanks. Had to give it to sticky bit because he had the extended explanation slightly before you did. Darn close though!

Answer (score 0):

i think  `natural join` is the problem

Natural Join is a variant of INNER JOIN where join condition is implicit on common column from both tables. In your case, the query in Natural Join can be written as below which will not return any result since it will try to match both A and B

```
select *
from table1
natural join table2
```

The same can be written in Inner Join like below

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.text1 = t2.text1 and t1.text2 = t2.text2
```